# SQL Server 2016 get JSONObject from JSONArray using JSONPath

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @json_str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
 '{"Customers":
    [{"Id":1,"Name":"Basavaraj",
            "Address":{"State":"KA","Country":"India"}},
     {"Id":2,"Name":"Kalpana",
            "Address":{"State":"NY","Country":"United State"}}
    ]
 }'
 SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json_str,'$.Customers[0].Address') AddressObject
```

If we execute above query it is returning Customers Address object.

### AddressObject

{"State":"KA","Country":"India"}

I want get single Customer object according to property like

```
DECLARE @json_str NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
     '{"Customers":
        [{"Id":1,"Name":"Basavaraj",
                "Address":{"State":"KA","Country":"India"}},
         {"Id":2,"Name":"Kalpana",
                "Address":{"State":"NY","Country":"United State"}}
        ]
     }'
     SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json_str,'$.Customers[].State') AddressObject where AddressObject="NY"
```

### AddressObject

{"State":"NY","Country":"United State"}

can we do this in SQL server 2016?

Comment: Your both examples return 1 row, but the second one has wrong country?

Comment: I have changed expected output

Comment: is their any way to specify all element in Customers Array

Comment: Have you read the documentation? For example this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx